# Powershell's LDAP Searching Not Returning Extended Schema Attributes

Tags: windows, powershell, ldap, schema

I am trying to search an LDAP Server (Not Active Directory Server) that has extended schema. The search returns results but none of the extended attributes from an extended object class (extending the inetOrgPerson object) are returned. What should I add to the following PS script to return those attributes?

```
   $ourServer="LDAP://myserver:9999"
   $ourPath="/somedn"      
   $ourAuth = [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::FastBind
   $Domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ($ourDN,"usersfulldn","password",$ourAuth)
   $ourSearcher=New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
   $ourSearcher.filter="(mail=someone@somewhere.com)"
   $ourSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("*")
   $ourSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mycustomattribute")
   $ourUser=$ourSearcher.FindAll() 
   $ourUser.Properties
```

It gives me all attributes but only from inetOrgPerson class. I have looked at the questions on this topic but some of them are dealing with Active Directory and not other LDAP Servers.

Comment: I finally ended up calling the application (Identity manager's) web service to get this extra attribute value but it will be great if someone can provide insight into a solution with native PS call

Comment: If you just leave the two lines `$ourSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add` commented out, do you have all the attributes the entry has?

Answer (score 0):

No. We still don't get extended attributes. We added properties to load lines after we didni't get the attributes without these statements